# Get main table records only from join with two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables "job_messages" contain 3 records and these all I want along with names from other 2 tables that are linked using foreign keys

here are the 3 tables:

[image]

Here are the SQL

```
SELECT 
  `job_messages`.`job_message_id`,
  `job_messages`.`job_time`,
  `job_messages`.`job_type`,
  `job_messages`.`work_group_id`,
  `job_messages`.`location_id`,
  `job_messages`.`patient_name`,
  `job_messages`.`room_no`,
  `job_messages`.`test_taken`,
  `job_messages`.`worker_id`,
  `job_messages`.`notes`,
  `work_group`.`work_group`,
  `locations`.`location_name`
FROM
  `job_messages`
  INNER JOIN `work_group` ON (`job_messages`.`work_group_id` = `work_group`.`work_group_id`)
  INNER JOIN `locations` ON (`work_group`.`work_group_id` = `locations`.`work_group_id`)
```

The problem I get 12 rows from this select along with repeated records and all I want are the main 3 records from "job_messages", what the correct SQL should be ?

Comment: Does your `work_group` or `locations` table contain duplicate rows for `work_group_id`? Or is it a `UNIQUE` field?

Comment: I think the problem is that theare are several locations for every work_group. So you get more rows then you expected

Comment: @Evgeny yes it is true so what is your advise ?

Comment: @Wel what value for `location_name` do you want to get in this case?

Comment: @Evgeny `location_name` value related to `work_group_id` in `job_messageses` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tryed changing Joining locations?

```
 INNER JOIN `locations` USING (`location_id`)
```

Or, if you prefer to use `ON`:

```
INNER JOIN `locations` ON (`job_messages`.`location_id` = `locations`.`location_id``)
```

Answer (score 1):

You say your table `job_messages` contain 3 rows, but you dont say how many rows are in the other two tables.

Your query looks ok, so i will guess the problem is the data.

try this querys.

```
SELECT `work_group_id`, count(*)
FROM `work_group`
GROUP BY `work_group_id`
HAVING count(*) > 1

SELECT `work_group_id`, count(*)
FROM `locations`
GROUP BY `work_group_id`
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

if any of those query return result you have a problem and that cause the duplicated rows.

EDIT

If you have multiple locations try using this

```
FROM       `job_messages`
INNER JOIN `work_group` 
        ON (`job_messages`.`work_group_id` = `work_group`.`work_group_id`)
INNER JOIN `locations` 
        ON (`job_messages`.`location_id` = `locations`.`location_id`)
```

OR

```
FROM       `job_messages`
INNER JOIN `work_group` 
        ON (`job_messages`.`work_group_id` = `work_group`.`work_group_id`)
INNER JOIN `locations` 
        ON (`work_group`.`work_group_id` = `locations`.`work_group_id`)
       AND (`job_messages`.`location_id` = `locations`.`location_id`)
```

Comment: yes the second query return 2 records, so what I should do ?

Comment: So why a workgroup_id have two locations? and I think something else is happen, otherwise the total of records will be 6 not 12. can you post that table data in your question?

Comment: You say two records, but what is the count? maybe 2+2? that will explain the 12 `3 * 4`

Comment: I think the location_id should be linked to job_messages.location_id like in  genespos answer

Comment: Yes, I just edit it my answer to reflect that, but you also can include and AND on the second join depend on what is your db logic.